# update datagridview based on checkbox value - Loop all the row's checkbox and check whether any checkbox has been selected

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So I have this DataGridView on which there are three columns, in this date and username are retrievied from my SQL Server database. Now, in the first column, we have a bit field which shows as a CheckBox in my Windows Application designer.

So, I want to, On clicking the update button my program wants to checks whether any checkbox has been checked if the checkbox has been checked then the update logic should trigger.

If there is no checkbox has been checked a error should be thrown out.

```
   public void Update_button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {


//Check all the checkbox in the first column and if none is selected throw error
            If(boolean(checkbox.Row[0]) == true)  { //This is an example if-else condition code which i expect 

     string msg = String.Format("Row: {0}, Column: {1}",
                 dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value,
                 dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex);
                MessageBox.Show(msg, "Current Cell");
                dataadapter.Update((DataTable) bindingSource1.DataSource);
                foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
                 if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value)) {
                  var myvalue = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Cells[0].RowIndex].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["dummy_id"].Index].Value.ToString();

                  var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                  using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
                   connection.Open();
                   using(var command = new SqlCommand(@ "[dbo].[SP]", connection)) {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = myvalue;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                   }
                  }
                 }

                }
                MessageBox.Show("SAVED");
                selected_user_data();

               }
// If no checkbox has been selected throw error.
               Else { 
                Messagebox.show("Please select checkbox")
               }
```

Comment: So what issue you are facing with this code /

Comment: The code works fine but I'am struggling with the if condition to verify whether any checkbox has been selected. I don't know how to loop all the row's checkbox and check whether any checkbox has been selected.

Comment: Please edit your question and state exactly the question you mentioned in the comment. A question should be stated in the post itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem before, my solution was to add all my GUI elements (in your case checkboxes, my case textboxes) to make them easy to iterate through. You can then check their state:

```
List<CheckBox> checkbox_list = new List<CheckBox>();
//proceed to manually add all checkboxes to this list upon program initialization
checkbox_list.Add(checkbox1);
//...
//so on until you are done

bool check = false; //we are looking for at least one true, so start with false
for(int i = 0; i < checkbox_list.Count; i++)
{
    if(checkbox_list[i].Checked == true)
        check = true;
}

if(check == true)
    Console.WriteLine("At least one checkbox is checked.");
else
    Console.WriteLine("No checkboxes checked.");

//use "check" bool to determine whether to update
```